Disable browser/page navigation while horizontally scrolling iframes?
My site has a container of iframes placed side-by-side, which creates a horizontal scroll. When users use a two-finger gesture/trackpad scroll outside the iframe, it scrolls as expected. However, when users initiate the scroll inside the iframe, it tries to navigate forward and backward. How do I prevent this navigation behavior?
<div className="flex overflow-x-auto">
  {VIDEOS.map((url) => (
    <div className="p-4 bg-red-200" key={url}>
      <iframe
        className="flex-none aspect-video"
        src={url}
        {/* other attributes removed for brevity */}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>


you can use the scrolling attribute on the  element and set it to "no".


<div className="flex overflow-x-auto">
  {VIDEOS.map((url) => (
    <div className="p-4 bg-red-200" key={url}>
      <iframe
        className="flex-none aspect-video"
        src={url}
        scrolling="no"  // Add scrolling="no" attribute
       
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>



This attribute tells the browser not to show scrollbars for the iframe content and to disable scrolling inside the iframe itself

Thanks for the suggestion, but scrolling is a deprecated attribute.
